# Cannot migrate database for Pagodabox project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm following the Hands-On project for course Laravel Essentails on Tutsplus. I created an app on PagodaBox and cloned it into my local system. After that, I install Laravel-4-Generator from https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators and generated resources for my project: model, view, controller, database seed, etc. 
Next, I try to run

```
php artisan migrate:install snippets
```

But I got the following error:

```
[PDOException]                                                                               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I don't know what's homestead user here.
Here is my database file for this project

```
'default' => 'mysql',
'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => isset($_SERVER['DB1_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_HOST'] : 'localhost',
        'database'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_NAME'] : 'snippets',
        'username'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_USER']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_USER'] : 'root',
        'password'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_PASS']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_PASS'] : '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

And here is the result when I check grants for 'homestead'@'localhost':

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'homestead'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for homestead@localhost                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'homestead'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8.......F' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

P/S: I have created the snippets database in mysql and I'm an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.
Has anyone experienced this before. What should I do as I don't understand what the error is here.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DB1_USER']` is your database username

Comment: No. I used Laravel 4 quickstart from pagodabox.com and this setting was automatically generated by pagodabox. I just change the database to 'snippets'. Btw, I tried to remove those $_SERVER[..] things. But the problem still remains. @JordanDoyle

Comment: do you have a user 'homestead' at your local mysql?

Comment: No, I don't. Actually, I tried to create homestead in mysql, and grant all privileges to that account but it didn't resolve my problem!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733626/php-mysql-connectivity-error/23734447#23734447 check this

Comment: @fortune I created the 'homestead' user but it did not resolve my problem at all.

Comment: have u updated the database connection in you php script accordingly?

Comment: @fortune Yes. The configuration now is: 'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'snippets',
   'username'  => 'homestead',
   'password'  => '1234',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
  ),

I can log in to mysql with this homestead account on command line

Comment: @DucCuong have u apply mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; at mysql cmd

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't help. I've tried to recreate that user on mysql, grant privileges, flush privileges three times and the problem keeps occuring

Comment: @DucCuong have you checked in php.ini file that extension=pdo_mysql.so is enabled?

Comment: you can do it with phpinfo(); it shows that pdo for mysql is enabled or not

Comment: @fortune Yes, it's enabled...

Answer (score 0):

View Users created:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------+----------------------+
| user | host                 |
+------+----------------------+
| root | %                    |
| root | 127.0.0.1            |
| root | ::1                  |
| root | imac.de.yadira.local |
|      | localhost            |
| root | localhost            |
|      | mor-mac.local     |
+------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

copy imac.de.yadira.local and replace hostname in my case it was mor-mac.local

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('imac.de.yadira.local'),

));
```

and now runs:

```
mor-mac:resposive yadira$ php artisan migrate:install
Migration table created successfully.
```