# Website won't connect to XAMPP database

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "website";
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=website', $username, $password);
    
    /*$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Username = :name');
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 24);
    $name = "andrei";
    
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result['Username']);
    
    $dbh = null;*/
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

And this is the error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I don't understand what is the issue... the database name is spelt right, I double checked and if it is needed I can even post a screenshot of the phpmyadmin...

## EDIT

I see that in phpmyadmin

`Server type: MariaDB`

how can I change that to mysql?

Comment: `host=37.228.134.102`? Isn't your XAMPP on your local machine?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Noticed that, fixed, edited the above post, still same issue

Comment: Is MySQL running?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733626/php-mysql-connectivity-error

Comment: Does `127.0.0.1<MySQL Port>/phpmyadmin` work directly in your browser ?

Comment: @JasonKrs This is what I see in phpmyadmin `Server: 127.0.0.1 »Database: website` and I access it by localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: um... I see this in phmyadmin `Server type: MariaDB` how to change that to mysql?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654428/how-can-i-change-mariadb-to-mysql-in-xampp)

Comment: @JasonKrs Thank you, I am doing that right now.

Comment: Kind of solved it, I get so many errors but tutorials will never be enough explained :(, thanks

Comment: for the record maria db is damn near a copy of mysql, xampp switched to it on purpose.